# checking if multiple input values are not empty

Tags: jquery

I have a table with `64` inputs and i want to check if all input values inside table `#Matrix` are **not empty**. If at  least one input value is not empty then we are okay. Below is what i am trying.

It only returns true if only the very first input is not empty.

```
if (!$('table #Matrix1 input').val()) {
    console.log("Empty");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `.filter` to filter the empty inputs. This will give the length of the empty inputs. Like:

```
var empty = $('#Matrix1 input').filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim() === ''; //Get the value and trim. Return true if equals to an empty string
}).length;
```

Here is a snippet.

```js
$('[type="button"]').click(function() {

  var empty = $('#Matrix1 input').filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim() === '';
  }).length;

  //console.log(empty);

  if ( $('#Matrix1 input').length === empty ) console.log('All are empty. Return false.');
  else console.log('Not all are empty');

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Matrix1'>
  <input type="text" value='1'>
  <input type="text" value='1'>
  <input type="text" value='1'>
  <input type="text" value='            '>
  <input type="text" value='     '>
  <input type="text" value=''>
</div>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Doc: [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: when all are empty it should return false. When at least one is not empty true

Comment: So just check if `empty > 0`

Comment: or `if (empty === 64) return false;` Thanks anyway

Comment: @GragasIncoming I would advise against doing it that way. If you add or remove an input in the HTML, you break your JS code.

Comment: yes but if one input (out of 64) is filled it should return true. With your suggestion, i have to fill all 64 inputs to return true.

Comment: @GragasIncoming, if you want to get the total count of the input, you can `$('#Matrix1 input').length`, instead of hardcoding the value